# Write multiple data frames to correct excel sheets using for loops

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, xlsx, r-xlsx

I have a nested `for loop` situation where I am looping through several excel work sheets, applying several functions, generating a **single** `data.frame` from each work sheet, and writing all of this back to a **new** work book whose sheet names are the same as the original work book.

At the moment the sheet names are correct in the new work book, but the `data frames` keep writing over each other so that every sheet has the same `data frame`. How can I get each `data frame` to write to its respective excel sheet?

```
library(xlsx)
library(agricolae)

#Read all worksheets in one file
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
 sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
 x <-    lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
 names(x) <- sheets
 x
  }

mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets("Loop_help.xls")`

for (i in 1:length(mysheets)){  #loop through sheets in workbook

file<-as.data.frame(mysheets[i])

  for(i in 2:ncol(file)){    #loop through columns in sheets

if(var(file[,i]) > 0){   #exclude columns that are all zeros

#create data frame (df)  
#do stuff

}
  #dostuff

  }

  #do more stuff

  n<-excel_sheets("Loop_help.xls") #sheet names

  for (i in 1:length(mysheets)) {#write new sheets to excel
    if (i == 1)
      write.xlsx(df, file="Loop.Help.xls", sheetName = n[i])
    else write.xlsx(df, file="Loop.Help.xls", sheetName = n[i],
                    append = TRUE)       
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end with `write.xlsx`, where is `objects` being created?

Comment: You nest the same loop at the end, reusing `i`. Try removing second `for (i in 1:length(mysheets))` but keep the if/else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Parfait for leading me to this answer.

Not only did I have a superfluous `for loop` in there, but I was calling `i` in both loops, when I needed to use a different letter (`k`).

Here is the final code:

```
for (k in 1:length(mysheets)){#loop through sheets in workbook
  file<-as.data.frame(mysheets[k]) 

  for(i in 2:ncol(file)){#loop through columns in sheets

if(var(file[,i]) > 0){#exclude columns that are all zeros

  #create data frame (df)
  #do stuff
  }
  }
  #do more stuff

  n<-excel_sheets("Loop_help.xls") #sheet names

          if (k == 1)
      write.xlsx(df, file="Loop.help.xls", sheetName = n[k])#write first sheet
    else write.xlsx(df, file="Loop.help.xls", sheetName = n[k],
                    append = TRUE) #append additional sheets

  }
```

Comment: How/where would I add in the filepath if I want it saved somewhere besides my wd?